# Django Email Change Form Setup

Tags: python, django, django-forms

My email change form for users works, but I feel like my code is not written correctly. If I did it the way I have done below, I'd need a thousand else statements so that the page would return a response. Can someone tell me how I can make this more efficient/better? I'm not sure of the conventional way to do this

Views.py

```
def email_change(request):
    form = Email_Change_Form()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = Email_Change_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if request.user.is_authenticated:
                if form.cleaned_data['email1']  == form.cleaned_data['email2']:
                    user = request.user
                    u = User.objects.get(username=user)
                    # get the proper user
                    u.email = form.cleaned_data['email1'] 
                    u.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/profile/")
    else:
        return render_to_response("email_change.html", {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest a complete change on how you looked at this. In my opinion, you should have all the implementation on the form side.

#### `forms.py`

I've implemented a class based on the [SetPasswordForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.SetPasswordForm) that is more complete:

```
class EmailChangeForm(forms.Form):
    """
    A form that lets a user change set their email while checking for a change in the 
    e-mail.
    """
    error_messages = {
        'email_mismatch': _("The two email addresses fields didn't match."),
        'not_changed': _("The email address is the same as the one already defined."),
    }

    new_email1 = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("New email address"),
        widget=forms.EmailInput,
    )

    new_email2 = forms.EmailField(
        label=_("New email address confirmation"),
        widget=forms.EmailInput,
    )

    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = user
        super(EmailChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean_new_email1(self):
        old_email = self.user.email
        new_email1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_email1')
        if new_email1 and old_email:
            if new_email1 == old_email:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['not_changed'],
                    code='not_changed',
                )
        return new_email1

    def clean_new_email2(self):
        new_email1 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_email1')
        new_email2 = self.cleaned_data.get('new_email2')
        if new_email1 and new_email2:
            if new_email1 != new_email2:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    self.error_messages['email_mismatch'],
                    code='email_mismatch',
                )
        return new_email2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        email = self.cleaned_data["new_email1"]
        self.user.email = email
        if commit:
            self.user.save()
        return self.user
```

This class checks both if the e-mail have in fact changed (very useful if you need to validate the e-mail or update mail chimp for example) and produce the appropriate errors, so they are helpful for the user in the form view.

#### `views.py`

Your code adapted to my class:

```
@login_required() 
def email_change(request):
    form = EmailChangeForm()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = EmailChangeForm(user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/profile/")
    else:
        return render_to_response("email_change.html", {'form':form},
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

As you can see the view is simplified, assuring everything on the form level.
To ensure the login I set a decorator (See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required)).

Ps: I changed `email1` and `email2` to `new_email1` and `new_email2` to be consistent with the Django approach on passwords. I also changed the form `Email_Change_Form` to `EmailChangeForm` according to Python guidelines for classes.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest moving the validation to the form clean method:

```
#form
class EmailChangeForm():
..
..
 def clean(self):
     if self.cleaned_data.get('email1', None) != self.cleaned_data.get('email1', None):
             raise forms.ValidationError('Validation Failed')


@login_required('/login/') //You can check the user is logged in using the decorator
def email_change(request):
    form = Email_Change_Form()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = Email_Change_Form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
                    user = request.user //Don't know why you want to get the object from database when you already have it
                    user.email = form.cleaned_data['email1'] 
                    user.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect("/accounts/profile/")
    else:
        return render_to_response("email_change.html", {'form':form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Update:
Doing this is redundant:

```
user = request.user
u = User.objects.get(username=user.username)
```

Because user is going to be the same as u i.e. `user = u`

Comment: What do you mean I already have the user? Do you mean I can use request.user.email = form.cleaned_data['email1']? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Updated the answer. Take a look

Answer (score 0):

You will create more complicated code with nested `if`, if you write every bit of logic in your views. You need to break them in appropriate sections. Like, for every form related validations, do it in forms like -

```
if `email1` is same as `email2`, 
 and if email1 is valid
```

check it in your form. You should check that in clean or clean_FieldName methods. Refer here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other

Another check you applied for authentication - if the user is authenticated or not. In this case, can a Unauthorised user change his email - well no. So why should I let my code run for it. It would be better to check this condition as soon as possible and then send the user to login page. @login_required is used to check this condition as a decorator of your view. See here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#the-login-required-decorator

If you really want to check your user authentication in your view, I think the good approach would be -

```
def email_change(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        // Do what you need to say to user or send them to login
        // return HttpResponse object / HttpResponseRedirect

    form = Email_Change_Form(request.POST) 
    if request.method=='POST': 
        if form.is_valid():
            ...
    else:
        ...  // Display form.
```