# Implement a password reset similar process for email change in django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

With the original `allauth` module, one username can have multiple email addresses. I want to limit every username to be associated with one email only, and in order to be more secure for a user to change his email, the process should be similar to password reset:

> 1. User request a email change, and an email should be sent to his old email address to verify the ownership
> 2. User clicks the link in that email, and now he's redirected to a page to set a new email address, then confirmation email should be
>      sent to this new address
> 3. User clicks the confirmation link to verify the ownership of the new email

I've checked `ResetPasswordForm` and couldn't quite understand how and where the `temp_key` is saved for later check when user clicks the link, since these two lines is commented off:

```
# save it to the password reset model
password_reset = PasswordReset(user=user, temp_key=temp_key)
password_reset.save()
```

And obviously there's no `PasswordReset` model either, so could anybody explains a bit more about this? Or instead of implementing it myself is there any other plugins/modules I can use for the whole process?

Answer (score 0):

`allauth` gives you the option for unique email-addresses, see [here](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/account/models.py#L37).

And for the E-Mail change workflow, I'm not aware of any packages, that cover your usecase fully. To implement this, however shouldn't be too much of a hassle, since you are just editing a regular Field of the user object. The only tricky part is, that you want to first send an email, containing a link that is only accessible for this user. So I would suggest to just implement it the way you suggested:

- create a view for the email reset, where the user puts in his email address
- send email with one-time link (see how it is implemented for e.g. the password reset in the django core [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L235))
- The generated needs to redirect to the view where you an input the new email.

All the crucial information you need happens on the second bullet above. You basically generate a token for this use. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734890/django-email-change-form-setup), you can see the example of a email_change form with the corresponding validation.

Hope that helps!